# Windows powering off after login

Tags: windows-7, windows

As soon as I logon to Windows 7 64bit, the computer restarts.

It isn't a hardware issue, as linux works fine.

Windows 7 64 bit.

Safe mode, last known good configuration etc, nothing makes any difference. Nor does startup repair or sfc.

I used DaRT to check the event log, and nothing is recorded.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: How do you know it is not a hardware issue, just because Linux doesn't reboot doesn't make it a software issue. What is Windows has drivers for a particular piece of hardware that is causing the reboot, whereas Linux doesn't have the driver and the device is not being activated under Linux?

Comment: Because I was using Windows perfectly until I installed an update, and I use Linux in the exact same way. I have not added or changed any hardware since.

Comment: That is important information. Which update was it that you installed?

Answer (score 1):

When booting Windows, press F8 repeatedly. At the menu, disable auto reboot. You will likely get a BSOD with a stop error. Note the stop error and look it up on the net. There are many things that could be happening, but this should get you started.

Comment: I should have said in my question that that didn't work either :(

Even with automatic reboots disabled, it reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its not a software error thats causing it like maybe a virus? And quite possibaly it could be a hardware error for hardware that Linux isnt using. Maybe your drivers are corrupt? MAybe your best bet is to use linux back up everything and do a factory reset or a hard format. This would eliminate the software issue.

Comment: Even if it is a software problem, I should be able to see what the problem is - even if I can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If it reboots with auto-reboots disabled, it's more than likely a temperature issue. Your power is being cut to keep the processor from overheating (regardless of how likely that may be).